# What should be the behaviour of API validation if we pass extra/unnecessary key value pair to api payload?

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose Api is expecting two key value pairs in the payload. I know we can validate these two pairs using express-validator or any. But what if  I pass third key value pair. Should API return error something like exceeded objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This decision is really up to you when you define your API.

In a standard REST API, data provided outside the requirements of the expected payload should return an error. Typically, you'd return a `400 Bad Request` to indicate the provided payload did not meet expectations. One way to assure this is to use a data validation tool, like [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi), to test your incoming payload for correctness.

Some, like myself, consider the [HTTP Status Codes](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) to be specific to the underlying communications protocol rather than the internal format of a request. In this view, all successfully received requests return a `200` with something like `{ok:bool, message: string}` such that, in the case of a successful operation, the result would be

`{ok: true, message: "success"}`

and in the case of error,

`{ok: false, message: "incomplete payload"}`.

If your specific use-case demands looser validation (perhaps in the case where you do not control the incoming payload), you could validate only those fields you require and silently ignore any extraneous data.

Comment: Thank you :) . I think i got the reference/option "removeAdditional" in Joi which will validate extra pairs and reject them if we do not need it.